# Best way to route method calling from List in Java

Tags: java, polymorphism, overloading, instanceof, visitor-pattern

What's definitely the best way to call a different method of a class according to a different object type in a List?

*common example:*

```
public class Dog extends Animals{
  ...
  public void say(){
    System.out("i'm a dog");
}

public class Cat extends Animals{
  ...
  public void say(){
    System.out("i'm a cat");
}

public class OtherClass {
  public void route(){
    List<Animals> aList = new ArrayList<>();
    a.add(new Dog());
    a.add(new Cat());
    for(Animals a:aList)
     methodOverloaded(a); ---> that's the point <---
  }
  public methodOverloaded(Dog d){
    d.say();
  }

  public methodOverloaded(Cat c){
    c.say();
 }
}
```

Of course, the metaphorical goal is print `I'm a dog` on the first iteration and `I'm a cat` on second running `methodOverloaded()`.

I tried

- Visitor Pattern
- `instanceOf()`

but I'm looking for better solution.

edit : I stricrtly want to call the overloaded methods of example's `OtherClass`.

Comment: Please read my updated answer, maybe it will be more clearly now.

Comment: thank you very much

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The best way is to define abstract method in Animal and override it in child classes. That's how the polymorphism works.

No need of overloadings.

```
public abstract class Animal {
    public abstract void say();
}

public class Dog extends Animal {

    @Override
    public void say() {
        System.out.println("Bark");
    }
}

public class Cat extends Animal {

    @Override
    public void say() {
        System.out.println("Meow");
    }
}
```

**Usage**:

```
public class Main() {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        List<Animals> aList = new ArrayList<>();
        a.add(new Dog());
        a.add(new Cat());
        for (Animals a : aList)
            a.say();
    }
}
```

**Output**:

```
Bark
Meow
```

**____UPDATE_1**

I would like to add some comments why the overloading these methods is not a good idea.

If you will add the following to your code - it will compile:

```
public methodOverloaded(Animal a) {
    a.say();
}
```

But it will not work as you're expecting. It will call `public methodOverloaded(Animal a)` for all the elements of `List`.

Why does this happen?

For all iterations of the loop, the compile-time type of the parameter is `Animal`. The runtime type is different in each iteration, but this does not affect the choice of overloading. Because the compile-time type of the parameter is `Animal`, the only applicable overloading is the third one.

**The behavior of this program is counterintuitive because selection among overloaded methods is static, while selection among overridden methods is dynamic.**

The correct version of an overridden method is chosen at runtime, based on the runtime type of the object on which the method is invoked.

This can be fixed with:

```
public methodOverloaded(Animal a) {
    if (a instanceof Cat) ? "Meow" : 
       (a instanceof Dog) ? "Bark" : "Unknown Animal"
}
```

Of course suggested option with overriding methods demonstrates better approach and more clean code.

Also, a safe, conservative policy is never to export two overloadings with
the same number of parameters, because it can confuse the client of the API. You can always give methods different names instead of overloading them.

But there is the case when at least one corresponding formal parameter in each pair of overloadings has a “radically different” (when it's clearly impossible to cast an instance of either type to the other) type in the two overloadings.

For example, `ArrayList` has one constructor that takes an `int` and a second constructor that takes a `Collection`. It is hard to imagine any confusion over which of these two constructors will be invoked under any circumstances.

Comment: ok but what if i stricrtly want to call the overloaded methods of example's **OtherClass**?

Comment: You can do it, but it's not a good way do design your classes. Both your methods can be combined in one, because they have shared logic on the same abstaction. Dependency inversion principle encourages working with abstractions. If you have other goal, please describe it, I will try to help. In your example, it doesn't make sense to overload these two methods.

Comment: The best practices for your requirement is to use factory design pattern in java.

Comment: @tommasoballardini Please read factory design pattern, you ll get the answer.

Answer (score 0):

You need to define the method in Animal and make it abstract

```
abstract class Animal {
    public abstract void say();
}
```

this way, you can override this method in each child of Animal, and all you got to do is `a.say()`
each object will call their respective method.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it like this:

```
for(Animals a:aList){
    if(a instanceof Dog){
        methodOverloaded((Dog) a);
    }else if(a instanceof Cat){
        methodOverloaded((Cat) a);
    }
}
```

But according to the scenario you have described in the question, @J-Alex answer is a good way to go.

Answer (score 0):

I can show you how "Factory Design pattern" is the suitable way here.
Define you main class like:

```
public abstract class Animal {
    public abstract void say();
}


public class Dog extends Animal {

    @Override
    public void say() {
        System.out.println("Bark");
    }
}
public class Cat extends Animal {

    @Override
    public void say() {
        System.out.println("Meow");
    }
}

public class FactoryClass{

public static Animal getCorrectAnimal(String type){
 if("Cat".equalsIgnoreCase(type)) return new Cat();
 else if ("Dog".equalsIgnoreCase(type)) return new Dog();

return null;
}

}


public class TestFactoryClass {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Animal an = ComputerFactory.getCorrectAnimal("Cat");
        List<Animals> aList = new ArrayList<>();
        a.add(FactoryClass.getCorrectAnimal("Dog"));
        a.add(FactoryClass.getCorrectAnimal("Cat"));
        for (Animals a : aList)
            a.say();
    }

    }

}
```

Trust me, if you will analyse the level of Abstraction here, it is awesome. **The client/consumer never has to know the Dog or Cat class, he/she just has to know the type and a general abstract class Animal.** You can even get rid of type here if you use one higher level of abstraction; you can read "Abstract Factory Design" for that. In this way, you expose the least of your class features (like here you exposed Dog and Cat class by using them directly with new in main class). Please upvote if you are satisfied.

Comment: @tommasoballardini Also no casting or direct use of class is needed here.

Comment: `Factory` is Creational Design pattern, the 'routing' mechanism here is still Polymorphism. You did the same thing but with another object creation approach. And a `Factory` doesn't make sense if you have a public constructor. Don't mess the responsibilities of different components of the application.

Comment: @J-Alex  that is why it is one of the best way. Please try to understand the question asked by tommasoballardini. Do you not agree it is the better approach?